# Arabic with LuaTex 1.12.0

Tags: luatex, arabic

I have used for the installation of arabic support of LuaTex `texlive-collection-langarabic` and `texlive-hyphen-arabic`. But since LuaTex 1.12.0 supports arabic lang by default I'm curious if these two packages are still required.

The question arise since I have no clue what these packages do and where to search to get an idea for the dependencies. I didn't find any hints on CTAN. Could be as well that I didn't search properly. Anyway - do I still need them if I use the features from LuaTex (=`luahbtex 1.12.0`)?

Comment: You might want to mention what you mean here by `texlive-collection-langarabic`, are these Debian packages?

Comment: ahhh... thx for the hint. Yeah its a package of `OpenSuse`. Now I understand and the q is somehow clarified.

Comment: The important question is probably whether Arabic fonts are available without those debian/opensuse packages. Mind though, that I personally never use the latex from a Linux dist, I find then to often lack updates.

Comment: @daleif: Yeah, but how do make than the updates? manually? Up till now I used the package mechanism. Therefore curious about how to do differently...

Comment: Using tlmgr, super tool, which the Linux fists cripple as they want you to get the updates through them